# live chat api package in rocket.chat project

Tags: rocket.chat

I am looking for livechat api package in rocket.chat project on github as I need to create an additional API for pagination.

I have got the rest api package but I cannot find the package where livechat APIs are defined

Answer (score 1):

A search of the code base quickly yields the package.

All of the files for LiveChat are included in the rocketchat-livechat package found here: https://github.com/RocketChat/Rocket.Chat/tree/develop/packages/rocketchat-livechat